# Get all string between a string separator

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I need a c# function that takes a string:

Input: `"str1__value__xyz__str4__"`

I want to convert it to an array (or list) of string

Output: `string[] output = { str1, value, xyz, str4}`

I think we can use Linq or a regular expression.

Comment: `string[] result = source.Split(new string[] { "__"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: `Regex` and *Linq* solution: `string[] result = Regex.Matches(source, "[^_]+").OfType<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: Why would you use regex? No need to complicate things

Comment: The reason for my downvote is that there is no evidence you've researched your own solution or tried anything yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Input.Split(new string[] { "__" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```